# Pandas DateTime for Month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have month column with values formatted as: 2019M01
To find the seasonality I need this formatted into Pandas DateTime format.
How to format 2019M01 into datetime so that I can use it for my seasonality plotting?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format` parameter:

```
print (df)
      date
0  2019M01
1  2019M03
2  2019M04

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%YM%m')
print (df)
        date
0 2019-01-01
1 2019-03-01
2 2019-04-01
```